# How can I add dynamically expression {{}} in ng-click angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this following issue. I want to show the table that is generating dynamically. I want to add the table name in ng-click and which is generating through a ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in coins">
    <button class="tablinks" ng-click="{{key}}">{{key}}</button>
</div>
```

As you can see I want the value of that {{key}} to be set on my ng-click.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is possible...or at least how ng click is meant to be used.
Instead, use a function that accepts that "key" variable as its parameter to do your dynamic thing.

E.g

{{key}}

and in your controller somewhere:

```
$scope.onTabClick = function(key) {
    if (key == 'tab1') {
        // do something with tab 1
    }
    if (key == 'tab2') {
        // do something with tab 2
    }
    etc
}
```